# Avoid the class scope so as to pass a member function as a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'll describe my question using the following sample code.

I have class B defined as follows:

```
class B
{
    public:
        inline B(){}
        inline B(int(*f)(int)) :myfunc{ f }{}
        void setfunction(int (*f)(int x)) { myfunc = f; }
        void print(int number) { std::cout << myfunc(number) << std::endl; }
    private:
        int(*myfunc)(int);
};
```

I then define class A as follows:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(int myint) :a{ myint }{ b.setfunction(g); }
    int g(int) { return a; }
    void print() { b.print(a); }

   private:
   B b;
   int a;
   };
```

To me the issue seems to be that the member function g has the signature `int A::g(int)` rather than `int g(int)`.

Is there a standard way to make the above work? I guess this is quite a general setup, in that we have a class (class B) that contains some sort of member functions that perform some operations, and we have a class (class A) that needs to use a particular member function of class B -- so is it that my design is wrong, and if so whats the best way to express this idea?

Comment: Yes, declare this function `static`. Alternatively, use an interface class, where you will define an abstract function `virtual int g(int)=0;`. Derive class `A` from this class: `class A : public <Interface Class Name>`. Then, pass an instance of this class to those functions in class `B`.

Comment: Since you tagged C++11/14, might I suggest using a `std::function` with a lambda? It's going to cost you a bit, but there's no better way.

Comment: Google "member function pointer C++"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::function:

```
class B
{
public:
  inline B() {}
  inline B(std::function<int(int)> f) : myfunc{ f } {}
  void setfunction(std::function<int(int)> f) { myfunc = f; }
  void print(int number) { std::cout << myfunc(number) << std::endl; }
private:
  std::function<int(int)> myfunc;
};

class A
{
public:
  A(int myint) :a{ myint } {
    b.setfunction([this](int a) {
      return g(a);
    }
    );
  }
  int g(int) { return a; }
  void print() { b.print(a); }

private:
  B b;
  int a;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and apologies if this is a elementary question as I don't know much about std::function and lambda's. So from what I understand [this] (int a) { return g(a) } wraps the "constant function" g(a) to make it look like a function of the form int A::(int), and std::function "strips" this off further to make so that it becomes int(int). Why does [](int a) {return g(a); } not work?

Comment: @DonShanil [ ] - is capture determines which symbols will be visible inside lamba body, g is member function of your class, so if you want to call it you have pass into [] this to make it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could generalize the class `B`. Instead of keeping a pointer (`int(*)(int)`), what you really want is any thing that I can call with an `int` and get back another `int`. C++11 introduced a type-erased function objection for exactly this reason: [`std::function<int(int)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
class B
{
    using F = std::function<int(int)>
public:
    B(){}
    B(F f) : myfunc(std::move(f)) { }
    void setfunction(F f) { myfunc = std::move(f); }
    void print(int number) { std::cout << myfunc(number) << std::endl; }
private:
    F myfunc;
};
```

And then you can just provide a general callable into `B` from `A`:

```
A(int myint)
: b([this](int a){ return g(a); })
, a{ myint }
{ }
```

Comment: I think you are missing the placeholder in `std::bind`.

Comment: @Holt Thanks for reminding me why I never use `bind()` :)

Comment: Thanks Barry! Just in trying to understand the "any thing that I can call with an int and get back another int" -- why is it that standard functions are not considered of type std::function<int(int)>. So for example, if I change [this](int a) to [&] (int a) all is well, but [] (int a) is not allowed?

Comment: @DonShanil : You're calling `g` which is a member function, so you need to capture the instance on which to call it...

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::function` and `std::bind`

```
class B
{
    public:
        inline B(int(*f)(int)) :myfunc{ f }{}
        void setfunction(std::function<int(int)> f) { myfunc = f; }
        void print(int number) { std::cout << myfunc(number) << std::endl; }
    private:
        std::function<int(int)> myfunc;
};

// ...
A a;
B b(std::bind(&A::g, &a));
```

Also note that you should initialize the function pointer to some default value (most likely null) and check for it when using, otherwise it's value is undefined.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the member function `A::g`.

```
class B
{
    public:
        inline B(){}
        inline B(std::function<int(int)> f) :myfunc{ f }{}
        void setfunction(std::function<int(int)> f) { myfunc = f; }
        void print(int number) { std::cout << myfunc(number) << std::endl; }
    private:
        std::function<int(int)> myfunc;
};
class A
{
    public:
        A(int myint) :a{ myint } { 
            b.setfunction(std::bind(&A::g, this, std::placeholders::_1)); 
        }
        int g(int) { return a; }
        void print() { b.print(a); }

    private:
        B b;
        int a;
};
```

Note you need to change the type of functor from function pointer to [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which is applicable with `std::bind`.

<kbd>[LIVE](http://rextester.com/AMP68235)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it.